# Why does the second argument of trigger arrive as an object?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

**Nevermind, I found out the answer. It is because the first argument of the incScore function is the event, while the second event is the actual passed in argument.**

I am trying to increase the score attribute of a Quiz object, but I am having some difficulty. I am using a global trigger event to increase the score after the user correctly answers a question:

```
global.trigger('incScore', 300);
```

Here is the incScore function:

```
incScore: function(change) {
  alert(JSON.stringify(change));
  this.set({
    score: this.get("score") + change
  });
},
```

I want to increase the score by 300 points, so I send 300 as the second argument of the trigger method. I thought it would pass 300 into the incScore function, but it passes in some sort of object. I am printing out the object's contents, and it is all sorts of garbage. How do I access the 300 that should've been passed into the function?

Answer (score 0):

First you should observe `incScore` event

```
initialize: function() {
    global.bind('incScore', _.bind(this.incScore, this));
},
incScore: function(event, score) {
    console.log(score)
}
```

if you triggering jquery event first argument will be event object and starting from second argument there will be your data.
[Link to jquery api](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)